# I get ',' Expected error when using useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am just starting out with JS and ReactNative, so please excuse me if this is too noobish of a quesation...

I am following a tutorial on youtube and following what the author does to the last step.

In this case he uses a useEffect and for him it works but i get a  ',' Expected error. (at each `:`)

```
useEffect ( effect: () => {
    console.warn( data: 'useEffect is called');
    if (originPlace && destinationPlace) {
        console.warn( data: 'Redrect to results');
    }
}, deps: [originPlace, destinationPlace]);
```

You can take a look at https://youtu.be/sIRcN0MeZVU?t=6758
(should jump start at 1:52:38) and you see his code and it works for him.
I am on Windows though, he is on Mac.

Another issue i had was on line 9 and 10 in his code - he has (initalState: null); i was getting an error that expects it to be wrapped in parenthesis and i did that like this `({initalState: null});`

Can you please explain why is this happening on my end, but not on the author's end and how should i fix it?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look like valid js syntax. Try with

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.warn('useEffect is called');
    if (originPlace && destinationPlace) {
        console.warn('Redrect to results');
    }
}, [originPlace, destinationPlace]);
```

One comment though, I see the author shows the code but he's doesn't seem to show it working, he moves to another topic, so it's not clear that it actually worked for him.

Edit2: I just notices what happens there, he's not typing the `effect:` and `deps:` strings, it's some kind of extension that he's using that shows the name of the argument but you shouldn't type that part. All those `something:` strings you see for the arguments is just some extra information added by the code editor but it's not actual code, so for the example you shared with `(initalState: null)`, it's actually just `(null)` but the extension is showing the name of that thing for reference (but you DON'T code that).

It's a bit confusing that somebody teaches with that without clarifying what's going on there or how to do the same in your code editor

Answer (score 1):

In `console.warn( data: 'useEffect is called');` the `data:` is noly type hint added by editor. So you should only use `console.warn` like simple `console.log`.

```
console.warn('useEffect is called');
```